# Circle intersection area

Tags: code-golf, math, array, geometry

## Description :

Given `x` and `y` positions of two circles along with their `radii`, output the area of intersection of the two circle.

---

## Input :

You will be given following input :

```
array 1 = x and y positions of circle a
array 2 = x and y positions of circle b
radius  = radii of the two congruent circles
```

### Input method :

```
([12 , 20] , [20 , 18] , 12)     ---> two array and number
([12 , 20 , 20 , 18] , 12)       ---> array and a number
(12 , 20 , 20 , 18 , 12)         ---> all five numbers
('12 20' , '20 18' , 12)         ---> 2 strings and a number
('12 20 20 18' , 12)             ---> string and a number
('12 20 20 18 12')               ---> one string
```

---

## Output :

- A non-negative integer (no decimal) equal to area of intersection of two circles.
- A string equal to the above mentioned integer.

#### Note :

- Output must be >= 0, since area can't be negative.
- In case of decimal round down to nearest integer

---

## Examples :

```
([0, 0], [7, 0], 5)                   ---> 14

([0, 0], [0, 10], 10)                 ---> 122

([5, 6], [5, 6], 3)                   ---> 28

([-5, 0], [5, 0], 3)                  ---> 0

([10, 20], [-5, -15], 20)             ---> 15

([-7, 13], [-25, -5], 17)             ---> 132

([-12, 20], [43, -49], 23)            ---> 0
```

---

## Winning criteria :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

## Suggestions :

- Provide a TIO link so it can be tested.
- Provide an explanation so others can understand your code

These are only suggestions and are not mandatory.

Comment: Ravioli, ravioli...

Comment: @FrownyFrog: Excuse me ? I am not aware of what you are talking about? nvm check on internet and I am sorry to report that is part of the problem. see the tag that says math and geometry. It is a good excuse to brush up on your math. What do you think. But if you disagree I think I will update the question and add formula.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Change `answer must be positive` to `answer must be >= 0` - If the circles don't intersect (as in examples 4, 7, 10) then the correct answer is 0, which last I checked is not positive.

Comment: @manassehkatz : Ok , sure. Done

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

*Alternate formula suggested by @ceilingcat*

Takes input as 5 distinct parameters **(x0, y0, x1, y1, r)**.

```javascript
with(Math)f=(x,y,X,Y,r)=>-(sin(d=2*acos(hypot(x-X,y-Y)/r/2))-d)*r*r*2>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBboMwDIbvewqOSZUM4iSUHuANdm@PCNpBVZEK0FaentkJ1bR0iW0pypfff3ytv@qpGfv7LAfXntf1u5879lHPHb@U7CEWcRQnMfKykmzqB9aWsKsbN7FuubuZPeRRLPLE0zEFzmXLdyNuqCq1Nm6Y3O38fnOf7MIykWDsfbWcJ9tK00SZt/9QDOXzCRMKELFWJDkK@qr/yEIRodKG5r7@sohmEUl9AZNeSGXpQDgZsLEo/khpxMAGXu2fqI69Sq9pKKnBAcexsbEBXVBjLCYn6cM2BiRz8yKKt5ocFMGJspvoi1UF4VuGaIPPQAfRbP0B)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 77 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Takes input as 5 distinct parameters **(x0, y0, x1, y1, r)**.

```
(x,y,X,Y,r,d=Math.hypot(x-X,y-Y))=>(r*=2)*r*Math.acos(d/r)-d*(r*r-d*d)**.5>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNbsMgEIX3PYWXgMA2f46zsG/QfbK0TNK0ikKErSo@vTsDjqqSImYQmm/ePPgavodpDJ/3Wdy8O63nbiUPvvADP/LAXfc@zJfystz9TB7iwBdxpLTrSWCdoiywWB5GPxFXBSocg0qAw1HGStv3ch39bfLXU3n1H@RMal7A3sVsKS22VVWFNG//obBljCeMqFIZa3nRgGDM@o@sajNU2DQ85l8W0Dojca6CwA4hLV4QRwM2F4UXSQ2YsomXuyeqc68iahoMHLCH79jY3IBucTAk06D0fvsGIBvzIgpVjQ7a5ETaTfTFqlTpWQZpA21KJ9F6/QE)

#### How?

This is based on [a generic formula from MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) for non-congruent circles:

```
A = r².arccos((d² + r² - R²) / 2dr) +
    R².arccos((d² + R² - r²) / 2dR) -
    sqrt((-d + r + R)(d + r - R)(d -r + R)(d + r + R)) / 2
```

where **d** is the distance between the two centers and **r** and **R** are the radii.

With **R = r**, this is simplified to:

```
A = 2r².arccos(d / 2r) + d.sqrt((2r - d) * (2r + d)) / 2
```

And with **r' = 2r**:

```
A = (r'².arccos(d / r') + d.sqrt(r'² - d²)) / 2
```

*Note*: If **d** is greater than **2r**, `Math.acos()` will return `NaN`, which is coerced to **0** when the right-shift is applied. This is the expected result, because **d > 2r** means that there's no intersection at all.

Comment: `d*(r*r-d*d)**.5` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! Using `with(Math)` and moving the definition of `d` saves 2 more bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>66 57</s> 51 bytes

```
Floor@Area@RegionIntersection[#~Disk~#3,#2~Disk~#3]&
```

A `Disk[{x,y},r]`refers to the region circumscribed by the circle centered at `{x,y}` with a radius of `r`.

`RegionIntersection[a,b]` returns the intersection of regions `a`, `b`.
`Area` takes the area.
`IntegerPart` rounds down to the nearest integer.

Comment: For the record, I didn't see alephalpha's submission as I was doing my own.   His is a shorter (hence a more successful) entry, but I left mine in anyway.

Comment: You could replace `IntegerPart` with `Floor`.

Comment: @mathe,  Thanks.  If I use the dedicated Floor brackets, do you know how I am to count the bytes?

Comment: @DavidC each one is 3 bytes, so the substitution is neutral in this case for byte count. They're useful if the expression would otherwise need parenthesizing, though (-1 byte compared to `Floor[ ]`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>27 25 24</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
×,²I½
÷ÆA×²}_çHḞ
ạ/çḤ}
```

A full program accepting a list of the two centres as complex co-ordinates and the radius which prints the result (as a dyadic link it returns a list of length 1).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//w5cswrJJwr0Kw7fDhkHDl8KyfV/Dp0jhuJ4K4bqhL8On4bikff///1stNysxM2osIC0yNS01al3/MTc)**

To take the two co-ordinates as pairs add `Uḅı` to the main link, [like this](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9qZWxsef//w5cswrJJwr0Kw7fDhkHDl8KyfV/Dp0jhuJ4KVeG4hcSx4bqhL8On4bikff///1tbLTcsMTNdLFstMjUsLTVdXf8xNw).

#### How?

```
×,²I½ - Link 1, get [√(s²d² - s⁴)]: separation of centres, s; diameter, d
 ,    - pair = [s, d]
×     - multiply (vectorises) = [s², sd]
  ²   - square (vectorises) = [s⁴, s²d²]
   I  - incremental differences = [s²d² - s⁴]
    ½ - square root (vectorises) = [√(s²d² - s⁴)]

÷ÆA×²}_çHḞ - Link 2, get intersection area: separation of centres, s; diameter, d
÷          - divide = s/d
 ÆA        - arccos = acos(s/d)
    ²}     - square right = d²
   ×       - multiply = acos(s/d)d²
       ç   - call last Link (1) as a dyad (f(s,d)) = [√(s²d² - s⁴)]
      _    - subtract (vectorises) = [acos(s/d)d² - √(s²d² - s⁴)]
        H  - halve (vectorises) = [(acos(s/d)d² - √(s²d² - s⁴))/2]
         Ḟ - floor = [⌊(acos(s/d)d² - √(s²d² - s⁴))/2⌋]
           -  ...Note: Jelly's Ḟ takes the real part of a complex input so when
           -           the circles are non-overlapping the result is 0 as required

ạ/çḤ} - Main link: centres, a pair of complex numbers, c; radius, r
 /    - reduce c by:
ạ     -   absolute difference = separation of centres, s
      -   ...Note: Jelly's ạ finds the Euclidean distance when inputs are complex
      -            i.e. the norm of the difference
   Ḥ} - double right = 2r = diameter, d
  ç   - call last Link (2) as a dyad (f(s,d))
      - implicit print
```

Comment: numbers only. And what is that [-7+13j,-25+-5j] ? I don't have that example. You might have to explain what you did ?

Comment: I explained it in the answer already... they are co-ordinates on the complex plane... I can do `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]` instead but it costs 3 bytes. (Note also that `-7+13j` **is** a number :)) -- the  `[-7+13j,-25+-5j]` corresponds to the example that returns `132`, `[-7, 13], [-25, -5], 17`

Comment: I don't know Jelly so I am lost on that. Also I sent the message before the explanation.  But yeah , sure this works (I guess?)

Comment: It's nothing to do with Jelly per-se, it's just mathematics. A point in 2-space is the same as a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Comment: Not what I meant. Normal languages I would be able to read and tell what is going on. Jelly and other such languages are a pain to read.

Comment: ...there will be an explanation when I am done :)

Comment: Well I will read it and hopefully learn a thing or two about it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

```
Floor@Area@RegionIntersection[#~Disk~#3,Disk@##2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY8xC8IwEIX/ymHAKQGTtFoHJYIIbuJaOhSJWtQW2myh/ev1Lokuee/uy71LPrV72k/tmls932EH8@nddb059LY2V/touvbcOtsP9ubQl2w6NsNrYpqTGsZUtZwvfdO60jM2cliA2MOCw71krKqWYIwB7/2Kwwqp30TNyf@bqJJMOLzPOazJJNWhKfJ0OWnsShxVoU1cSMqNtRe4SoZbQhEjJDcRKRwTWWAZJWzRRqQLiinIZ2u0AaV3YYF7Y2SRwmX8iZDqtzjTlE1jSo/j/AU)

Comment: +1 `Floor`.  Of course!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>83 79 71</s> 66 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c,d,e){float g=cacos(hypot(a-c,b-d)/e/2)*2;e*=(g-sin(g))*e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDbaoQwFEXf/YowpZBIUs3NcbDTL@lLJl7By1DtQxnm12tPdJQWbcg5kMPaOzuxrLB2fKpaW3@m2Ws/pFX3Ur5566QxQwmDMceGXqilKc3ILa87M6DibI3telx@XbsBG2bphaUkyAJBfJFk/hkXrK9aXBDiZ8l9rNoBNQYG5OZdP@CU48Nz@t4eKMpxSBHs49Q1IQl6rCBAXP2Hw@ZTrQKHC7HlNUURGE9d/rUX8RZneg4y9V884OGWdhkElFMxrt1hkrgwesccXskloELPGn5ccbmTnU3eypW76ATftPA7YWTsQkBTkbvitHwP0JHaMwdCujTxnIrrxXwvOhfzU5VTKJAK@TAPvfv4bfPaFP3I6uYH)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 106 chars with centers given as lists

```
from numpy import*
def f(a,b,r):d=min(1,hypot(*subtract(b,a))/2/r);return(arccos(d)-d*(1-d*d)**.5)*r*r//.5
```

## 100 chars with center coords separately

```
from math import*
def f(a,b,A,B,r):d=min(1,hypot(A-a,B-b)/2/r);return(acos(d)-d*(1-d*d)**.5)*r*r//.5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 83 bytes

```hs
(k!l)m n r|d<-sqrt$(k-m)^2+(l-n)^2=floor$2*r^2*acos(d/2/r)-d/2*sqrt(4*r*r-d*d)::Int
```

Just the formula, really. Type has to be declared as `Int` for NaN to map to 0 with `floor`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNCsIwEEDhq0whi5mRUIg/i2IP4CUKwSiWTJI6ydK7x@ri8a3ey9f4EOkd4yCUIIN@wtXWtzaD0SZa3AHF5t35KaWocayLY38vFcPoRiW7w78BT6ysNnCgabrl1pNfM8yw6ZobGMCB4AyXf8f@BQ)

Comment: [alternate formula](https://tio.run/##HcVBCsMgEADAr2wgh12LBAzpITQP6CcKUhsirmuzeuzfbelhmMPX9GLuHdPAlEFAP@FmnfHPUrGe2hCTzfRwF2Qrv2nSydG2cyk6YrA1CgYio0bX9S6tZx8FNnhrlAYj4ECwwPVv7l8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 69 bytes

```javascript
with(Math)f=(a,b,c,d,r)=>(-sin(x=2*acos(hypot(a-c,b-d)/2/r))+x)*r*r|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcJRCsIwDADQ6yQ1dWMgftUbeIgs3WxlNCMtOsG7V@S9J7@4iuW9@aJx6f2dW4I7t4RrAKaZhCIZhhv4mgscYXIsWiF9dm3AXmj2EYdpMMTTgc6cfccuWqpuy3nTB6ww0t@VLoj9Bw)

Short not sure if it can be golfed any further. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 56 bytes

```perl6
{{1>$_&&{$_-.sin}(2*.acos)}(abs($^p-$^q)/2/$^r)*$r²+|0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBDsIgFET3noLFTwOltNAGuzB6FAgaSZqorbBqKJfyCF4MBePmTebNLFd326f7iiqLjikEcQJdVQE0a/30iLivW3OZPYnYnD0GtTBQT9L1HShHanDvF914TN6syOINNEF2djvMKZ8aNBZK0vwFpyKH4Fkx@ZsLh2JGKoZvYb1kMv9Gckgf)

Takes circle coordinates as complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 119 bytes

```
=INT(IFERROR(2*E1^2*ACOS(((C1-A1)^2+(D1-B1)^2)^.5/2/E1)-((4*E1^2-((C1-A1)^2+(D1-B1)^2))*((C1-A1)^2+(D1-B1)^2))^.5/2,0))
```

Input taken as 5 separate variables:

```
x-coordinate    y-coordinate    x-coordinate    y-coordinate    radius
     A1              B1             C1                D1          E1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 109 bytes

```python
from math import*
a,b,x,y,r=input()
d,R=hypot(x-a,y-b),2*r
print int(d<R and R*r*acos(d/R)-d*sqrt(R*R-d*d)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5bjsMgDPznFChfgEAtkPQhbS7BDWjIKvlIoJSVktNnbVKJGdnjsYe0lymu5hhiGPumaY7fHBe6@DLReUkxF0G8fMlN7jL385r@CuMkSNdPe4qFbcrLXb24NCKTlOe1UAALP476NVAnsvBD/LBwcVwF8XnnwpxwUAZ@MfyARDJu40AxX@jrwa6SwrtX7jj59vB0BSidpDeYVbbQq@40V0YBnQaAA6U7bNAGN7UFxXTnSN9RrcYWgVtPiAbVPnATqL3hwvObXCuLNx7nLY0/VNqceS1OWrAYy/8B)

Pretty straightforward. Get the distance between circles, and use `R=2r` as a substituite in the equation. `d<R and` to short-circuit if circles don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 63 bytes

```
J@+^-hhQh@Q1 2^-ehQe@Q1 2 2K*2eQs&<JK-**KeQ.tcJK4c*J@-*KK*JJ2 2
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%40%2B%5E-hhQh%40Q1+2%5E-ehQe%40Q1+2+2K%2a2eQs%26%3CJK-%2a%2aKeQ.tcJK4c%2aJ%40-%2aKK%2aJJ2+2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%5B7%2C0%5D%2C5%0A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C10%5D%2C10%0A%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%5D%2C3%0A%5B-5%2C0%5D%2C%5B5%2C0%5D%2C3%0A%5B10%2C20%5D%2C%5B-5%2C-15%5D%2C20%0A%5B-7%2C13%5D%2C%5B-25%2C-5%5D%2C17%0A%5B-20%2C-4%5D%2C%5B-40%2C29%5D%2C7%0A%5B38%2C-18%5D%2C%5B46%2C-29%5D%2C10%0A%5B-29%2C33%5D%2C%5B-8%2C13%5D%2C15%0A%5B-12%2C20%5D%2C%5B43%2C-49%5D%2C23&debug=0)

Takes input as a triple consisting of two doubles and a number.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 122 bytes

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(Geometry::Parse('POINT'+a).STBuffer(r).STIntersection(
             Geometry::Parse('POINT'+b).STBuffer(r)).STArea())FROM t
```

(line break for readability only).

Uses MS SQL's support of [spatial geometry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

[Per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), SQL can take input from a pre-existing table **t** with `int` field **r** and `varchar` fields
**a** and **b** containing coordinates in the format `(x y)`.

My statement parses the coordinates as `POINT` geometry objects expanded by the radius using the function `STBuffer()`, then taking the `STIntersection()` followed by the `STArea()`.

If I am allowed to input the *actual* geometry objects in the table instead, then my code becomes almost trivial (48 bytes):

```
SELECT FLOOR(a.STIntersection(b).STArea())FROM t
```